# CakePHP 2.1 code for Html <link> tag

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I am using CakePHP 2.1 and I am having this tag in my program.. How to convert this tag into CakePHP 2.1 code?

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="css/default/small-screens.css" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css('css/default/small-screens.css', 
    null, array('media' => 'screen and (max-width: 480px)')); ?>
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::css